# Failover web hosting with multiple NS

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, failover

Are there any drawbacks in having each nameserver entry in a domain name point to different failover server? In this setup, the same DNS server will also serve the content - so if it's down, the alternate nameserver will be loaded instead, which will then point to itself.

I understand that this setup has its limitations (e.g. each domain will be restricted to only one "protected" server/service), but are there any limitations I might have overseen?

Comment: what nameserver are you using and how many servers are in the domain?  This is kind of an unconventional approach and of course there will be problems with DNS caching but I think your basic idea will work.